# Power sequencing: enable signal hold below threshold if asserted after supply

Tags: pullup, power-sequencing

**Short version:**

When I power my PCB and the SYS_EN signals at the same time, all voltage rails turn on. If I first power the PCB, then pull high the SYS_EN signal, the 3.3V and 1.8V rails don't turn on. SYS_EN only reaches 0.8V (instead of 1.8V) and consumes 5 times more current.

How can I identify the problem?

**Long version:**

I'm currently testing the first prototype of a PCB I designed.

It has 5 voltage rails:

- VDD (referenced to GND_alim): the supply voltage (24V nominal)
- 5V_ext (referenced to GND_ext): generated from VDD once POWER_GOOD goes high
- 5V (referenced to GND_iso): generated from VDD once POWER_GOOD goes high
- 3V3 (referenced to GND_iso): generated from VDD once SYS_EN goes high
- 1V8 (referenced to GND_iso): generated from 3v3 rail through linear regulator (no enable signal used)

The 3 grounds (GND_alim, GND_ext and GND_iso are isolate from each other).

POWER_GOOD goes high as soon as VDD > 18.6V

In normal use, the 5V rail is used to power up a computing SOM (ie module), which held low SYS_EN until it finished powering up, then SYS_EN is pulled up to 1.8V by an internal 10k pull-up resistor. I then use SYS_EN to enable the 3.3V regulator (which then turns on the 1.8V rail). I can't power up the 3.3V/1.8V rails earlier, because it would provide signals on the input of the computing SOM before it can accept them, which can damage it).

For now, to avoid damaging the computation SOM during the first tests, I removed it, and I generate manually the SYS_EN signal with a lab power supply (at 1.8V) and a 10k resistor.

If I turn both channels (VDD and SYS_EN) of the lab supply on simultaneously, everything works as expected (all power rails turn on, the current for the SYS_EN is 18-19µA, the voltage after the 10k resistor is around 1.65V).

If however I first power VDD, and later plug-in the wire for SYS_EN, the 3.3V rail don't turn on!

So far I observed in this second case:

- voltage for SYS_EN (after the pull-up resistor of 10k) is only 0.8V (too low to enable the converter generating the 3.3V). This voltage don't change (significantly) when replacing the pull-up with 4.7k
- the current on SYS_EN is far bigger (105µA with the 10k pullup, 207µA with the 4.7k pullup)
- the indicator LED for SYS_EN still turns on

The relevant parts of the schematics:

[image: 3V3_converter]

[image: SYS_EN_LED]

[image: sys_rq]

Not represented:

- the pull-up resistor (10k) connected between the connector and the lab supply (+1.8V with respect to GND_Iso
- the connector for the computation module (SYS_EN is not connected, because the computation module is not mounted)

The datasheets of the relevant components (if you want additional ones, just ask):

- [TXU0101DRYR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txu0101.pdf): the level shifter used to power the 3.3V rail (nb: both VccA and input are connected to SYS_EN)
- [ADUM163N1BRZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM160N-161N-162N-163N.pdf): digital isolator
- [RE1C002UNTCL](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/re1c002untcl-e.pdf): N-channel MOSFET

Do you have any idea where the issue might be, and/or how to investigate further?

I had a look around with the scope, but without noting anything that seemed of interest: if you want some scope view, just ask, I will be happy to provide (nb: one of our scope has isolated inputs, so can have different grounds for each of the 2 channels).

I checked the test point RST_RQ: it is solid 0V with respect to GND_iso.

I checked if I'm not just pulling too much current on SYS_EN (which is not strongly driven, but just pulled up towards 1.8V through a 10k resistor). The worst case (if I read the datasheets correctly) is the following:

[image: worst case current]

It isn't great, but it's not enough to explain the 1V voltage drop in the 10k pull-up resistor (and it's only a worst case scenario: when powering everything at one, it's only 18-19µA, most of which is due to R11 (I will increase it to 5-10M in the next revision)).

So my guess is some component is consuming far more current than specified for "normal" conditions in the datasheet because of some issue with the power rails. My main suspects are therefore:

- [TXU0101DRYR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txu0101.pdf) (the level shifter): I use SYS_EN to both power the input side Vcc (VccA) and the input pin. According to the datasheet, current consumption on VccA can go quite a bit up if the input isn't driven strong enough:

[image: input voltage vs current]

Maybe there is something similar (or worse) happening when both Vin an VccA are at some "intermediate" voltage, causing "high" (>100µA) current to be drawn, therefore reducing further the voltage (due to IR drop in the 10k pull-up)

- [ADUM163N1BRZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM160N-161N-162N-163N.pdf): the current leakage on the input pin with the corresponding supply voltage turned off might be higher than the 10µA max in normal operation (I haven't found any specification about input leakage current when supply is off, only about the output state in this situation)

NB: the usual solution would be to unsolder the different components one by one to find the culprit. However, this PCB is quite dense, and most of the components are really small (TXU0101DRYR is just 1*1.45 mm), so unsoldering them without damaging the rest of the PCB will be difficult, and re-soldering them again is clearly above my skills (and those of the rest of our small company). So the only way to do such tests is to send the PCB back to the manufacturer (which will be quite time expensive, specially if we have to try it several times). So I'm keeping rework on the PCB as a last option if the rest fails.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be, or how best to proceed to identify it?

**EDIT 1 :**
I found an interesting note I had missed in the datasheet of the ADUM163N1BRZ (note 4 in the image bellow) :
[image]

This seems to explain my problem : the 1.8V rail isn't powered yet, so the ESD diodes of the inputs are connected to GND_Iso potential (approximatively) : therefore SYS_EN is shorted to ground through the ESD diodes, ie capted at their threshold voltage (which seems to be around 0.8V).

I don't get however why it works when SYS_EN is pulled up simultaneously to VDD

**EDIT 2 :**
To test my hypothesis, I cut the trace between the test point T28=SYS_EN and pin 2 of the ADUM163N1BRZ : it didn't solved the problem. So eve if the datasheet warned about the ESD diodes, it doesn't seem to be the problem.

So my main suspect is now again TXU0101DRYR (the level shifter) that uses SYS_EN both as input and as VccA (low level power supply). But this time, I see no way to test it without destroying irremediably the PCB (or sending it back to the manufacturer to unsolder the TXU0101DRYR, which is far beyond my skills )